# PostgreSQL \lo_import and how to get the resulting OID into an UPDATE command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, postgresql

I'm working with Postgres 9.0, and I have an application where I need to insert images into the remote `server`. So I use:

```
 "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -c  "\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'";
```

where

`192.168.1.12` is the IP address of the server system

`5432` is the Port number

`myDB` is server database name

`my_admin` is the username

`"\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'"` is the query that is fired.

[image: Shell screenshot]

After the image has been inserted into the database I need to update a row in a table like this:

```
UPDATE species 
SET    speciesimages=17755;  -- OID from previous command.. how to get the OID ??
WHERE  species='ACCOAA';
```

So my question is: how do I get the `OID` returned after the `\lo_import` in psql?

I tried running `\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'` in Postgres but I get an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'""
LINE 1: "\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'"
```

I **also** tried this:

```
update species
set speciesimages=\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'
where species='ACAAC04';
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2: set speciesimages=\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'
                          ^
```

Comment: What is the language of your application? In most languages there are functions to do client-side lo_import, it's easier than launching psql in a separate process and getting the OID back.

Comment: @DanielVérité : iam using `delphi 7` for the front end

Comment: Delphi has several PG drivers. If using [pgdac](http://www.devart.com/pgdac/) you might look at [this code sample](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14083). If using [zeoslib](http://zeos.firmos.at/) there is apparently a TZPostgreSQLBlob object that probably implements  the functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your file resides on your local machine and you want to import the blob to a remote server, you have two options:

1) Transfer the file to the server and use the [server-side function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-funcs.html):

```
UPDATE species
SET    speciesimages = lo_import('/path/to/server-local/file/zzz4.jpg')
WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
```

2) Use the [psql meta-command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) like you have it.

But you cannot mix psql meta commands with SQL-commands, that's impossible.
Use the psql variable `:LASTOID`  in an `UPDATE` command that you launch immediately after the `\lo_import` meta command in the same psql session:

```
UPDATE species
SET    speciesimages = :LASTOID
WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
```

To script that (works in Linux, I am not familiar with Windows shell scripting):

```
echo "\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg' \\\\ UPDATE species SET speciesimages = :LASTOID WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';" | \
psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin
```

- `\\` is the separator meta-command. You need to double the `\`, in a `""` string, because the shell interprets one layer.
- `\` before the newline is just the line continuation in Linux shells.

Alternative syntax (tested on Linux again):

```
psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin << EOF
\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg'
UPDATE species
SET    speciesimages = :LASTOID
WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
EOF
```

Comment: 1.`Transfer the file to the server` wont be possible in my case.. 2.how to use the `:LASTOID ` ?  `select :LASTOID as loid` doesnt work

Comment: @PresleyDias: It works for me, I just tested. Only works inside psql! The psql variable is substituted before the SQL command is sent to the server. Don't forget the `:` prefix.

Comment: `Only works inside psql! ` oh ok, i didnt think of that , i will try again

Comment: hey i tried this `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d nansis -U nansis_admin -c  " update species SET speciesimages = :LASTOID  WHERE  species='ACAAC24'"
` in CMD but i get this error `syntec error at or near ":"`

Comment: @PresleyDias: That won't work, because the `-c` switch just hands one SQL string to the server. For `:LASTOID` to hold a value, you need to execute the meta-command first and the execute the SQL command in interactive mode or like I demonstrated in my answer. I added another syntax variant for easy scripting. Examples are for a Linux shell.

Comment: ok, im doing like this 1.`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -c  "\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'";` then immediately (programmatically) im doing `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d nansis -U nansis_admin -c " update species SET speciesimages = :LASTOID WHERE species='ACAAC24'" `
`

Comment: @PresleyDias: That's two separate invocations of psql. It needs to be done in **one** session as I explained above.

Comment: Can you tell me how to convert you script to windows?

Comment: @PresleyDias: Sorry, I don't do scripting on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After importing an image with this command:

```
\lo_import '$imagePath' '$imageName'
```

You can then find the description of the binary by querying the `pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata` table which stores the oid value you need.

Ie:

```
"SELECT oid as `"ID`",
pg_catalog.obj_description(oid, 'pg_largeobject') as `"Description`"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata WHERE pg_catalog.obj_description(oid,'pg_largeobject') = '$image' limit 1 "
```

Comment: Or you could use `\lo_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it if your field is type `bytea`.

```
\lo_import '/cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/Downloads/Contract.pdf'
update contracts set contract = lo_get(:LASTOID) where id = 77;
```

Use `\lo_list` and `\lo_unlink` after you import.