# Postgres 9.0 linux command to windows command conversion

Tags: windows, linux, cmd, postgresql

I am working on an application using `delphi 7` as the front end and `postgres 9.0` as the back end.

I have to upload images to the server so i use `\lo_import` and `\lo_export` for inserting images on the server and geting the images from the server.

I had come across a problem where is needed the `LASTOID` after a `\lo_import` so i can use the OID to update a row in my table but i cant set the syntax correct in windows

```
UPDATE fishes
SET    fishesimages=17755;  -- <--last OID
WHERE  fishes='0A';
```

Here is my question on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786014/postgesql-lo-import-and-how-to-get-the-resulting-oid-into-an-update-command/9786524#comment12459997_9786524). I have got the answer but the script is a  Linux shell script. I cannot run it in Windows

```
psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin << EOF
 \lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg'
  UPDATE species
    SET    fishesimages = :LASTOID
    WHERE  fishes = '04';
EOF
```

and

```
echo "\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg' \\\\ UPDATE species SET fishesimages =   :LASTOID WHERE  fishes = '04';" | \
 psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin
```

I have tried this in windows

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -c "\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'";
```

then immediately (programmatically) im doing

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB-U myDB_admin -c " update species SET fishesimages = :LASTOID WHERE fishes='24'"
```

But I get `Syntax error at or near ":"`

Can anyone tell tell me how to covert it to Windows commnad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the commands in a file (say import.psql)

```
-- contents of import.psql
\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg'
UPDATE species
SET    speciesimages = :LASTOID
WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
```

than issue command

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -f import.psql
```

Comment: +1,hey
that worked, thanks alot..but i think you meant `.sql` and not `.psql`..please update so i can accept

Comment: @PresleyDias I meant `.psql`. The file extension doesn't matter to the program, but it is a way to signal the expected contents. The file contains a mix of SQL and psql-specfic directives. It would be a small lie to call it `.sql`. In fact this mix of sql + psql is exacatly why you couldn't issue both in a single `-c`. [command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by the server (i.e., it contains no psql specific features), or it is a single backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands. ](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)